# Spring Boot Internationalization message filename structure

Tags: java, spring-boot, internationalization, filenames

Spring boot allows you to customize message properties files by setting a basename followed by a the locale for example messages.properties and **messages_de.properties**.

I want to add a suffix to these files for example **messages_de_file1.properties**.

Is there a way to customize to use this file structure.
Or even better for example **/i18n/en/messages.properties** and **/i18n/de/messages.properties**.

The reason I need to do this is because of the automated translation service provider I am required to work with.

Answer (score 0):

There's a property for that:

> `spring.messages.basename` supports comma-separated list of locations, either a package qualifier or a resource resolved from the classpath root.

(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.internationalization)

So you can do something like

```
spring.messages.basename=i18n/en,i18n/de
```

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question however what I am actually asking is there a solution for using filenames with letters after the locale symbol like this example.

**messages_de_file1.properties**